# Italic is rendering in bold?

Tags: css

Today, font-style:italic in css is rendering my fonts in bold, only on Chrome and Firefox - not on Safari.

For instance, using this css:

```
em {
 font-style: italic;
}
```

and this HTML:

```
<p><em>Hi, I'm showing up in bold.</em></p>
```

displays in italics AND bold.

I've tried restoring CSS from two days ago before I noticed the bug, to no effect, so it seems like it's something other than the CSS causing this. I've tried validating the HTML and CSS, nothing shows up that seems to be the source.

An example of this shows on this page: https://critter.co/home/orgs/

Comment: I see what you mean, unless italics used to work, it appears to be related to the font(google-font) the site is using. If i change the font, it appears as italic, not bold.

Comment: Ah! This is a good clue. There's another issue: the 'strong' appears with letter-spacing .1em styling. I have other elements with that styling (h1-h5, nav), but not strong. And that's fixed, too, when I take away the font. How could the Google font be doing this? I'll try next uploading the font directly rather than downloading from Google.

Comment: It's best to include your code here then it is to link to a site.  If other users are having a similar issue and the site or content is changed since the problem occurs, this question becomes useless for future readers.

Comment: Hi Erik! Done - better?

Comment: The question was improperly edited by removing the URL (while copying just part of the code, and *not* the relevant part). Restored now. But a question should contain sufficient code to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actual link/code:    `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:800italic,400`

on your page...

You have just font-weight:800, for italic.

Change it with:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800italic,400italic,300,300italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

so you have all possible variations... P.S. Specify then font-weight in CSS, and rendering can be more consistent, in all browsers.

Comment: Good answer! If the OP only has oblique at the moment, that would explain why browsers are inconsistent in their displaying of the font i.e. Some apply oblique as the alternative, some default to none.

Comment: thanks! :) I don't understand why the display changed suddenly since I haven't changed this line in the past few weeks, but who knows. This answer makes sense to me.

I just replaced the font with this person's font: http://qrohlf.com/posts/better-opensans/ - and everything's fixed. Thanks for your help! :)